# os.listdir() not printing out all files

Tags: python, file, directory, listdir

I've got a bunch of files and a few folders. I'm trying to append the zips to a list so I can extract those files in other part of the code. It never finds the zips.

```python
for file in os.listdir(path):
     print(file)
     if file.split(".")[1] == 'zip':
     reg_zips.append(file)
```

The path is fine or it wouldn't print out anything. It picks up the same files each time but will not pick up any others. It picks up about 1/5th of the files in the directory.

At a complete loss. I've made sure that some weird race condition with the file availability isn't the problem by putting a time.sleep(3) in the code. Didn't solve it.

Comment: Do the filenames have more than one `.` in them, perhaps? Does `file.endswith('.zip')` work?

Comment: Thanks. Put it as an answer and I'll mark it. I'll chalk it up to exhaustion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible your files have more than one period in them. Try using `str.endswith`:

```
reg_zips = []
for file in os.listdir(path):
     if file.endswith('zip'):
         reg_zips.append(file)
```

Another good idea (thanks, Jean-François Fabre!) is to use [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext), which handles the extension quite nicely:

```
if os.path.splitext(file)[-1] == '.zip':
    ...
```

Am even better solution, I recommend with the [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob) function:

```
import glob
reg_zips = glob.glob('*.zip')
```

Comment: or use `os.path.splitext` which handles the last dot nicely.

Answer (score 0):

```
reg_zips = [z for z in os.listdir(path) if z.endswith("zip")]
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 I can explain it as the person who asked the question. This is a list generator which is doing this in memory: 

for each in the returned list of files in a directory path, if it ends in zip, put it in memory as "reg_zips". 

This is a pythonic way of doing things. If it had addressed the nature of my bug I'd have marked it answered.