# List Files from Directory with More than One Period

Tags: python-3.x, glob

I'm trying to list files from a directory. The problem is that some of these files have numbers after their extensions that look like `sample1.csv.1`. When I try to list files in the directory, these files are omitted from the list. This is not a problem for files like `sample.txt.1`. I've tried these 3 approaches:

```
import os 
path = 'C:\\my\\path\\here'
missingFiles1 = os.listdir(path)

missingFiles2 = []
for files in os.walk(path):
    missingFiles2.append(files)

import glob
missingFiles3 = []
withRegex = path + "\sample*.[0-9]" # Actual file starts with an L
for files in glob.glob(withRegex):
    missingFiles3.append(files)
```

I tried an iterator too but have already forgotten what the code looked like. I got some good pointers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45330919/os-listdir-not-printing-out-all-files) but I couldn't get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Using:

Python 3.6.8

glob3 0.0.1

Comment: I don't understand why these files in particular wouldn't be listed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\sample.[0-9]`
Should match sample.1, but not sample.txt.1 and not sample1.txt or sample1.txt.1

What you're looking for is not possible to express using glob patterns.

You could get all files starting with sample and ending in any extension and .1 using this glob-pattern:

`sample*.*.[0-9]`
This would fit any file starting with sample, followed by anything, followed by a dot, followed by anything followed by yet another dot and a number

Glob patterns are not regular expressions and you can't make it match "one or none".
Glob only knows:
`*` => any characters (1-N) or no character at all
`?` => one character, but not none
`[ab]` => either a or b, but not none
`[0-9]` => any from 0-9, but not none

You're looking to match a number or no number in front of the first extension and then  a number in the second extension if I understand you correctly.

```
import os 
path = 'C:\\Users\\mastacheata\\test'
missingFiles1 = os.listdir(path)

missingFiles2 = []
for files in os.walk(path):
    missingFiles2.append(files)

import glob
missingFiles3 = []
withRegex = path + "/sample*.*.[0-9]" # Actual file starts with an L
for files in glob.glob(withRegex):
    missingFiles3.append(files)

print(missingFiles3)
```

In C:\Users\mastacheata\test there are 3 files: findfiles.py, sample1.txt.1 and sample.txt.1

This is the output:

```
['C:\\Users\\mastacheata\\test\\sample.txt.1', 'C:\\Users\\mastacheata\\test\\sample1.txt.1']
```

Comment: It's a typo there is a `*` in the code. I tried your suggestion and some variations but as soon as I put in the second period, it skips the `for` loop altogether. You were able to get this to work?

Comment: I switched the backslash for a forward slash to be safe, but apparently it works either way. (\ , / , \\\ all yield the same result)

Comment: I can get the `.txt.1` extensions to list. It's the `.csv.1` that I'm struggling with.

Comment: The difference is not the extension. That doesn't matter to glob (unless you explicitly write it in your pattern)

Comment: Oh, now I see I completely misread your code.
I imagined there was a dot in front of the asterisk all the time, but there is none. m(
Sorry, that's definitely my fault, no idea why I didn't see that.

Your original script works just fine for me in python 3.8.2 on Windows 10

Comment: Success! Updating Python did the trick. Thanks for your help @Mastacheata.

Comment: Which version of Python were you using before? That could help others stumbling on this question.

I don't really know why this would behave differently in older versions of python, though. Seems strange because glob should just be passed to the systems underlying function.

Comment: I was using 3.6.8. It's on the end of the post under Using.

Comment: I must've been blind m(
Thanks